# Is there a way to copy the content of a set into an other set(different objet)

Tags: java, set

Is there a way to copy the content of a set into an other set(different objet) ?

addAll adds all the references of the source Set to the target Set. It doesn't create copies of the instances these references refer to.

Comment: I think it's something you need to do by hand. Java doesn't know how to create copies of custom objects, you need to write your own copy  method.

Comment: What do you mean by content? members of `obj1` to `obj2`? in that case are members of same type?

Comment: Deep copy requires explicit code from you. Otherwise it's always shallow copy.

Comment: Did you implemented the cloneable and after that used the object method clone ?

Comment: I will try to implement the clonebale method indicated in this link http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2014/03/how-to-clone-collection-in-java-deep-copy-vs-shallow.html

Comment: I you have any other documentation or help about this method

Answer (score 0):

The method addAll() doesn't clone the contents of the set, you have to do it manually and implement the clone method.

```
for (MyType t : mySet)
    otherSet.add( t.clone() );
```

Comment: `t.clone()` does not come out of box. The OP needs to define that method and implement `Cloneable`.

Comment: please, can you give more explanations how to implement Cloneable

Comment: Here is a part of my program                         Set<Set<Operation<Concept>>>    AndCombination = new HashSet<Set<Operation<Concept>>>();
   AndCombination.add(Sets.newHashSet(op1));
   
Set<Set<Operation<Concept>>>    AndCombinationCopy = new 
       HashSet<Set<Operation<Concept>>>(AndCombination);
for (Set<Operation<Concept>> t : AndCombination) {
 AndCombinationCopy.add( t.clone() );}                                                                       I get the message "The method clone() is undefined for the type Set<Operation<Concept>>"